# Incorrect Count when counting rows from AWS S3 bucket using Snowflake

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: Get the exact count of rows in the file including NULL

Issue: Count ignores Null count

Expectation: How to get a count of rows including Null values

```
SELECT count($1)
FROM @public.bckt/east/
     (file_format=> csv,pattern=>'.*/2020/08/23/abc.csv');
```

Here the first column in the file has some NULL values, If there are 10 rows in the file including NULL in the first field, I would expect to get 10 as count. But I get like 7 as count, with 3 of them been NULL values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out

```
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM (
        SELECT $1 
          FROM @public.bckt/east/
         (file_format=> csv,pattern=>'.*/2020/08/23/abc.csv')
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

A little tip that I've used is to use the metadata information that Snowflake provides on SELECT from a staged file.  For example,

```
SELECT 
  count(metadata$FILE_ROW_NUMBER), 
  max(metadata$FILE_ROW_NUMBER)
FROM @public.bckt/east/
     (file_format=> csv,pattern=>'.*/2020/08/23/abc.csv');
```

This will provide you a count and max for the FILE_ROW_NUMBER metadata of your file.  They should always be equivalent and will never be NULL.  Use either one of them, and you'll get what you're looking for.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html#metadata-columns

Comment: Nice tip, very handy

Answer (score 0):

Please try count(*) on the stage.

*Count(*) returns total count of rows in a table and count(column_name) will return count of rows with a non-null value in the column.*

Comment: count(*) isn't available when querying directly against a file.